# wordpress style menu manager

Tags: php, jquery-ui, menu, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a WordPress style menu manager for my own CMS using `php` and `jquery-ui`. I already made the first steps but I don't really know how should I carry on especially how to realize the parent-child relationship between menu items. My actual code looks like

```
<style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; height: 1.5em; }
html>body #sortable li { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; }
.ui-state-highlight { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>       
        <div class="admin_menus">
                            <ul id="sortable">
                            <?php foreach($menus as $menu): ?>
                                <?php if(array_key_exists('children', $menu)):?>         
                                <li class="ui-state-default">
                                 <?= $menu['name'] ?>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu_test">
                                    <?php foreach($menu['children'] as $menu_child):?>
                                    <li class="ui-state-default" ><?= $menu_child['name'] ?></li>
                                    <?php endforeach;?>

                                  </ul>

                                </li>
                                <?php else:?>
                                <li class="ui-state-default" ><?= $menu['name'] ?></li>
                                <?php endif;?>
                                <?php endforeach;?>                                                                         
                            </ul>
        </div>
```

where `$menus` holds my menu items retrieved from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin to implement draggable menu feature in your website
http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/

It is simple to use, and you can customize on your own.